# Using Iterator with Map

Tags: apex

Is it possible to use Iterator (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_iterable.htm) with Map in apex ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can since it's a collection of data

Comment: I mean by using the standard functions - next() and hasnext()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** : `Iterator` class is to be used with `List`. If you need to use it with a map you may work with the `map.values()`

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new Map<String,String>();
myMap.put('first','Chris Chard');
myMap.put('second','Chris Morris');
myMap.put('third','Nick Nothelfer');
Iterator<String> itr = myMap.values().iterator();  //return an iterator instance from map's values
while(itr.hasNext())
    System.debug('val : '+itr.next());
```

Simple iterator example with a map values.

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new Map<String,String>();
myMap.put('first','Chris Chard');
myMap.put('second','Chris Morris');
myMap.put('third','Nick Nothelfer');
for(String val: myMap.values())
   System.debug('Name : ' +val);
```

If you need to iterate over keys alter the `for` loop as

```
for(String key: myMap.keySet())
```

When you need to access map items while iterating, you can do something like below

```
for(String key: myMap.keySet()){
   String val = myMap.get(key);
}
```

Comment: I mean by using the standard functions - next() and hasnext()

Comment: `Iterator` class is to be used with `List` types. See the updated answer